# How Touch ID Basically works, and to use an alternate for user name password in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, touch-id

Hi I'm working on my some client's app in which I need to integrate touch ID, I googled and successfully integrated. Code is following.

```
 LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *authError = nil;
NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"Touch ID Test to show Touch ID working in a custom app";

if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
    [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
              localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                        reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                            if (success) {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Success" sender:nil];
                                });
                            } else {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                        message:error.description
                                                                                       delegate:self
                                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                    [alertView show];
                                    NSLog(@"Switch to fall back authentication - ie, display a keypad or password entry box");
                                });
                            }
                        }];
} else {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:authError.description
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    });
}
```

Now I've some queries.

- My client's app is already has login via username password feature, how to use an alternate touch ID feature I mean how touch or my app know that this user belong to some specific user after successfully touch id completed. I'm asking this because my client tell me to figure out this process.
- Is apple gives us some key after login from touch ID to detect user ?

Looking for help.
Thanks

Comment: @JustSid i think client will not agree to save password in keychain, if he'll agree then if user change their credential again and againd, do you think is that the good idea ?

Comment: @JustSid and if user delete app and reinstall ?

Comment: i think its the only way is to store the [username and password in the iOS keychain](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password) and retrieve it on a successful touch ID authentication. otherwise how else is the server going to know. should be using some hashing function as well to store the password in, but i assume you do something like that when sending the password to the server anyway

Comment: The TouchID process doesn't tell you anything about the finger that was presented, only that a valid finger was presented. You need to get the user to login once with username/password and store those credentials in the keychain and secure that with TouchID.

Comment: @fonix hashing the password before sending it to the server doesn't achieve anything. You need to secure the channel using encryption